# Making Ember API only accessible through browser

Tags: api, security, ember.js

I am building am ember app.  Naturally my backend is effectively a JSON API.  The problem is, while I want data exposed to users on a browser, I don't want people effectively downloading my database through curl requests.  One solution would be to require authentication to access the data, but I want the GET requests available to users without requiring them to sign in.  The reason for the concern is that I plan on keeping the rights to the data, even though I want to let users have access to small pieces at a time.  The only thing I can think of is rate-limiting IP addresses, although I'm sure there are easy work-arounds for an attacker.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Either your data is public or it's not. If you want it to be accessible to one client (the browser), you'll have to make it accessible to any client. If you want to protect the data, require authentication.